# How to use fix `forge update` error

Tags: solidity, evm, foundry, rust, forge

When I originally type `forge update` I get returned this:

`Error:  fatal: Needed a single revision Unable to find current origin/v1.3.0 revision in submodule path 'lib/forge-std'`

After following [steps](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-git) to update git to the latest version, (`sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` updated git for me. You can check what version you are using via `git --version`), I was able to get `forge update` to return only this:

`Error:  Unable to find current origin/v1.3.0 revision in submodule path 'lib/forge-std'`

But how can I get it to not return an error message at all?
[Here](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/3720) is a related thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the `forge update` command still works as expected, however, I was able to remove the error message by commenting out the `branch = v1.3.0` line inside of my .gitmodules file. Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/3720#issuecomment-1323474913) for the "cursed" solution.